# hackerranks's text processing units in UNIX -- how to take input?

Tags: unix, text-processing

I am trying to learn text processing units in Unix through hackerrank.com's practice problems.

One of the problems is this: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-cut-4

But I don't understand how to take inputs from standard output in unix, so I'm having trouble submitting my answer. Can you please let me know how to get started with taking inputs? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know that this is an old question, but I'll answer anyway, so everyone can have a response, if they need it.

As you can read [on the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut), the synopsis is `cut [OPTION]... [FILE]...`, so the FILE argument is optional (because it's surrounded by square brackets).

In addition:

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

So if you simply call `cut` command withoud any file specification, it will read from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

In the question we don't have to take input, we have to just display the first four characters from each line of text.

solution:

```
cut -c1-4
```